# Docker killing container "permission denied" due to AppArmor. Just why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apparmor

I am trying to kill containers I launched through `docker-compose`. Either by gracefully stopping (Ctrl+C) or by `docker-compose down` I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR: for <container-name>  cannot stop container: b60c1c4d886899504b...2a022e4d39429dc6ca6e4784afdd: Cannot kill container b60c1c4d886899504b...2a022e4d39429dc6ca6e4784afdd: unknown error after kill: runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:388: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

I am just looking for the answer **WHY**. I am trying to understand AppArmor better but understanding **WHY** I can't stop the containers before everything would help to understand what's going on.

I see that this is an error many people come across. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104733/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-when-killing-container) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109465/kill-docker-container-permission-denied) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126322/unknown-error-after-kill-did-not-terminate-sucessfully-signaling-init-process-c) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279514/how-to-stop-running-container-if-error-response-from-daemon-is-cannot-kill-con)
However, most of the answers suggest workarounds and no *solutions*. Even the explanatory answers like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104733/docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-error-when-killing-container) dive directly into AppArmor and profiles. From docker documentation I see docker has a default AppArmor policy `docker-default`. I partly understand the concept but still don't get **WHY** I can't stop the containers through the user and the environment I've started them in.

If I try to wrap my questions:

- I started some containers as a user, **WHY** can't I stop them. `sudo` does not work either. Who can stop them then?
- Do I need an AppArmor profile for each container?
- I don't feel it's a good idea to restart AppArmor or disable it. Should I do that? What is the ideal solution?

Any feedback or explanations welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to look at the docker logs if you want more information, maybe you find something there https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970134/2596409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact reason but came close. It seems there were conflicting docker installations on my Ubuntu 19.10 and this was causing this access control issue.

As stated [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36010), I've removed the snap installation. As I already had another installation I didn't have to install it via another way.

```
sudo snap remove docker
```